# How to recursively find permutations of a list using an arraylist?

Tags: java, recursion

Hey I've been looking around but unable to find out how to solve this problem.  I need to be able to take in an ArrayList and return an ArrayList containing a set of ArrayLists for each permutation of the original one.

For example:

`[2]` Returns `[2]`

`[4,5]` Returns `[[4,5],[5,4]]`

`[1,2,3]` Returns `[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]`

Here is my current code but obviously there are some problems with it:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> permutation(final List<Integer> list)
{
    // TO DO
    if (list.size() == 1)
    {
        List<List<Integer>> combinations = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        combinations.add(list);
        return combinations;
    }

    int first = list.remove(0);

    List<List<Integer>> per = permutation(list);

    List<List<Integer>> permute = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    for (List<Integer> li : per)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index <= li.size(); index++)
        {
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(li);
            temp.add(index, first);
            permute.add(temp);
        }
    }

    return permute;
}
```

Comment: When it's so obvious what the problems are, would you be so kind and list these? Thanks

Comment: Please give also an example, what a list with duplicates would return. For example: [1,2,1]

Comment: [Looks fine to me](http://ideone.com/5cSb6H).

Comment: This is a good example of recursion. You're taking your list, popping off all numbers until you're down to one which you return. In your for-each-loop you then take `per`, place that into a new `ArrayList` and place your other number at whatever index `index` is at in the for-loop. Return this new list and repeat. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

```
private static List<List<Integer>> permutations(List<Integer> list) {
    return permutations(list, 0, list.size());
}

private static List<List<Integer>> permutations(List<Integer> list, int start, int end) {
    List<List<Integer>> permutations = new ArrayList<>();
    if (start < end) {
        Integer nextInt = list.get(start);
        if (start == end - 1) {
            permutations.add(Arrays.asList(nextInt));
        } else {
            for (List<Integer> subList : permutations(list, start + 1, end)) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= subList.size(); i++) {
                    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>(subList);
                    newList.add(i, nextInt);
                    permutations.add(newList);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return permutations;
}
```